# Open and close Putty Terminal with Powershell scheduled

Tags: powershell, putty

Hi I want to write a script that should run each day automatically at a certain time and open a putty terminal for e.g. 2 hours and then automatically closes this connection again

```
plink.exe -ssh -l „username“ -pw „pw“ -L "port/ip" "servername"
```

This command worked for using Powershell to open the tunnel but how do I close it after 2 hours automatically and how do I start this command in the first place  automatically instead of manually?

any ideas? Thank you very much

Comment: Is this shell going to run something? Is this just to see if the host is alive during the two (2) hours? What is the use case for this?

Comment: It shall open the putty and then a user can update his/her local data extract from the mysql host via the putty connection

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'Task Scheduler' feature and create a scheduled task to start and stop it.

Comment: Why do this with a script, just put your command in a scheduled task. No other code required.

Comment: Thanks so far. I added a task in the windows cheduler to run a command (powershell) and as argument the -File and my filepath. Now Powershell opens at a specific time and runs the putty connection. But how do I tell it to close down and is it possible to not having a Powershell window popup but run it in the background? Thank you

Comment: set it to "Run whether user is logged on or not" if you don't want it to run in the context of your current desktop session.